# Get top values for each of the columns in the database in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I would like to execute the following command to retrieve the top values on all the fields of my database:

```
select top(100) COLUMN_NAME, count(*) as number
from DATABASE_TABLE
group by COLUMN_NAME
ORDER BY number DESC
```

That is, iterate through all the database tables, and all fields and calculate the top values.

How can I do this using a stored procedure or SQL query?  I know how to get all the fields of the database:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

but I don't know how to plug this into a stored procedure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need a programming technique known as [tag:dynamic-sql] to do this.

Comment: you will have to query `information_schema` tables, collect column names, build dynamic SQL like this `select max(someint), max(somestring), max(somedate) from sometable`, execute it and store results in some other table for further review

Comment: A quick google finds a whole bunch of similar questions which will give you the information you need e.g. [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60323172/select-unique-values-from-every-column-in-every-table), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52246897/get-data-from-every-column-in-every-table-in-a-database-sql-server), [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30247224/get-top-three-most-common-values-from-every-column-in-a-table).Please do your research first...

Comment: @DaleK in this case, why haven't you vote to close?